# App doesn't open in Android 8.0, any solution?

Tags: android, flutter

Hi I developed an Android app with Flutter. I  have tested and installed it in my Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 7.0.0 and all was right. When I wanted to test it in a Huawei Mate 10 with Android 8.0.0, it didn't open. I installed the final app first, and nothing occurred, there weren't any errors. Then I connected the phone to my PC and wrote "flutter run" and my console was this:

```
Initializing gradle...                                      25,3s

Resolving dependencies...                                   132,0s

Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         57,6s

Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.

Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                  4,1s
```

The app doesn't open and the cursor is in stand by. I don't know if the problem is Android v8.0.0 because I tested it in two Huawei Mate 10 with Android v8.0.0

Comment: I'm pretty sure EMUI prevents apps from being installed through ADB by default. There's an option somewhere around USB Debugging.

Comment: Go to Developer options and enadle 1)  OEM unlocking enable,2) USB debugging-ON, 3) Install via USB-ON. Set option for "Use USB for" to Transfer files(MTP) (from three/more options of Charging,Transfer files ,transfer photos...).  Some time USB setting would not allow to install. Make sure your instant Run setting is off in Android Studio.

Comment: It didn't help. Is any configuration that can select the android version or somethink like that?